# WSO2 - Unable to perform silent login using oidc library

Tags: wso2, x-frame-options, openid-connect

I am using oidc JS cilent library [OIDC JS](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki)

I have client code that connects to **WSO2** IDP sever using openID connect endpoints.The flow is **implicit** configured on WSO2 server

WSO2 version :wso2is-5.3.0

The normal login works fine. When it comes to silent refresh for access-token it fails. 
I am using "signinSilent"  method of oidc to do silent login via iframe  and get latest access token.

This works fine with Gluu server.

Here is the screenshot of error we are getting,
[image]

Error:

```
Refused to display '<idp authz url>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frmae-Options' to 'deny'
```

Comment: I suspect this is because WS02 does not allow x-frame option by default. I looked at the configuration but could not find to disable it.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041900/how-to-enable-x-frame-options-in-wso2-5-4-1

Answer (score 0):

You can go to {carbonhome}/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF and add this to HttpHeaderSecurityFilter:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This will disable the X-Frame-Options header and thus allow all domains. However, be careful when doing this. You can also set the antiClickJackingOptions and define the domains for which it is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this problem, the domain that will call the Identity Server, has to be added to the oauth2 web application shipped on WSO2 IS in its filter for CORS. To do it, just modify this file:

```
<wso2is_home>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

And add the base URL you are going to allow in param-name cors.allowed.origins:

```
[...]
<filter> 
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name> 
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class> 
<init-param> <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name> 
<param-value>https://whatever.com, https://whatever2.com</param-value>
</init-param> 
[...]
```

After modify this and restart WSO2 IS, the browser will not block it again

Comment: The error is not a CORS-issue as it's not trying to call a page via curl. This needs X-Frame-Options headers.