# How to enable X-Frame-Options in WSO2 5.4.1?

Tags: wso2, x-frame-options

I tried to configure my jaggery.conf file as stated in the documentation to allow framing as follows :

```
"filters":[
      {
        "name":"HttpHeaderSecurityFilter",
        "class":"org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter",
        "params" : [
            {"name" : "hstsEnabled", "value" : "false"},
                        { "name": "antiClickJackingOption", "value": "SAMEORIGIN" }
             ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter",
        "class": "org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter",
        "params":[
          {"name": "patterns", "value": "text/html\" ,application/json\" ,plain/text"},
          {"name": "filterAction", "value": "enforce"},
          {"name": "httpHeaders", "value": "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private"}
        ]
      }
    ],
```

Despite, in my client app, I still get a message saying that framing isn't allowed.

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://localhost:9444/authenticationendpoint/oauth2_error.do?oauthErrorCode=invalid_callback&oauthErrorMsg=Registered+callback+does+not+match+with+the+provided+url. does not permit framing.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this issue is coming from `authenticationendpoint`, you have to configure `HttpHeaderSecurityFilter` filter in the file `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/WEB-INF/web.xml` as follows.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Btw, the error in the shared URL is `Registered+callback+does+not+match+with+the+provided+url`, you can check whether the `redirect_uri` defined in the request URL is matching with the one configured in the service provider.